# Open WPF application in Windows in c++ application

Tags: c++, wpf, windows, process

I have a situation where I need to start a WPF application and have it run using a child window created by my C++ application.  So the sequence of events would be -

1. Start C++ application
2. C++ application creates a window that it wants WPF app to run in.
3. Launch WPF using [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  Included in create process would be the handle of the window that the WPF app is to use.

It looks like this should be possible, but I cannot find function calls/parameters to do this.  This will be in a Windows XP and Windows 7 environment.

Comment: Do you mean you want to box a WPF application in a C++ application, like a virtual panel with the application inside it?

Comment: @kyndigs - that is a good description of what the "other" team wants to do with the new app.  They have a large existing c++ app that they want this new functionality to run inside the virtual window the current UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup the WPF program as a library, not an application.  You could then provide it's user interface with direct access to your "child window", which it could host directly or via [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx).

Trying to launch a separate process, and share a window via a HWND cross process is going to be very problematic.